# Making sense of "residual" indices after boolean mask. Are they new columns or what?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, boolean

I have this issue using boolean masks in Pandas. It has to do with the integer index labels that seem to carry over from one DataFrame into another after applying a boolean mask. I applied a boolean mask to a DataFrame called `f500` and stored that in another one called `null_previous_rank`. The index labels of the first DataFrame survive in the filtered DataFrame, but I'm not sure what role they play there. They're not row indices of the new df. I played with a few different ways of making sense of them, which you'll see in the screenshots with comments. Hopefully, they'll make sense.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Boolean indexing issue screenshot 1]
[image: Boolean indexing issue screenshot 2]
[image: Boolean indexing issue screenshot 3]
[image: Boolean indexing issue screenshot 4]

Comment: Point taken. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the question is that the "residual" indices are row labels in the new DataFrame.

I guess the index doesn't appear when selecting a single entry but does appear when selecting a list or slice because when there are multiple entries, we need to keep track of them, but when displaying a single entry, there's no need to keep track?